# Well ordered Isomorphic sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

(ZF) Let A be a infinite set. Prove that if there is a well order
≤1 in A, then there is a well order ≤2 in A, for which <A, ≤1> and <A, ≤2>
are not isomorphic.

My attempt:
I start with the use of the definition of well ordered set, hence for every non empty B in A there exists a minimal element to ≤:
(∀ B)[B != ∅ & B ⊆ A → (∃ y)[y ∈ A & (∀ x )[x ∈ A → y ≤ x ]]].\

Also we say that <A, ≤1> is isomorphic to <A, ≤2> if there is a bijection f:A1-> A2 such that if for all x and all y, <x,y> is in R1, then <f(x1),f(x2)> is in R2.

If I asume that A1 and A2 are well ordered, then they have a minimal element x0,y0, respectively.Then if A1,A2 are isomorphic there is bijection f such that f(x0)=z1, z1 in A2. Since f preserves the order=> z1 != y0 is a minimal element-contradiction. Hence A1 and A2 are not isomorphic.

I beg someone to check my attemp. I will be thankful to anyone who share their ideas.

Comment: Unfortunately your proposed proof seems to prove that no two ordered sets are isomorphic, including an ordered set with itself! The flaw seems to be that $z_1$ might equal $y_0$, which means there's no contradiction.

Comment: @GregMartin You are right, but I thought that it cannot map the smallest element from A1 to the smallest in A2.

Answer (score 2):

There is no actual argument here. You start by assuming that there is an isomorphism $f$ from $\langle A,\le_1\rangle$ to $\langle A,\le_2\rangle$, and then you simply assert that this isomorphism is in fact not an isomorphism, because $f(\min_{\le_1}A)\ne\min_{\le_2}A$. Assuming something and then asserting its negation is not a proof by contradiction: it is simply asserting two contrary things independently.

Moreover, the result holds only for infinite sets, and nowhere have you used the fact that $A$ is infinite.

What you must do is assume that $\le_1$ well-orders $A$ and use $\le_1$ to **produce** a new well-order $\le_2$ that is not isomorphic to $\le_1$. I will tell you one way to do this, but I will leave it to you to prove that it works.

Let $a=\min_{\le_1}A$, the least element of $A$ with respect to the order $\le_1$. To form the new order $\le_2$, move $a$ to the other end. That is, define $x\le_2y$ if and only if $x\le_1y$ and $x\ne a$, or $y=a$. Pictorially, if $\langle A,\le_1\rangle$ looks like this:

$$a\;\bullet\;\bullet\;\bullet\;\cdots$$

then $\langle A,\le_2\rangle$ looks like this:

$$\bullet\;\bullet\;\bullet\;\cdots\;a$$

Comment: Thank you for the directions I will write to you my attempt: I assume that ≤1  well-orders A. Hence A has a min element with respect to ≤1. We denote it with a. We define function f: A≤1 to  A≤2; Let x and y be witnesses of how this funct works. Then f(x)=x1 and f(x2)=x2 with f(x1)>f(x2) if and only if x1>x2 and x is different from a.  Hence we had produced a new well order.

Comment: A is infinite, then it does not have a max element which means that f(a) can be mapped into infinitely many points in A2, since it is the smallest element in A1. So we assume that f(a)=a', such that a' is the largest element from a2. Will you have a look at this?

Comment: @Tiki: $\langle A,\le_1\rangle$ **can** have a maximum element. It might, for instance, be $\Bbb N$ ordered like this: $$2,3,4,5,\ldots,0,1\,.$$

Comment: Okay, I agree with you, but could you tell me wether my attempt is correct>

Comment: @Tiki: I’m sorry, but it simply doesn’t make sense. You say that you’re defining a function from $\langle A,\le_1\rangle$ to $\langle A,\le_2\rangle$, but you don’t actually define one. And defining one would not tell you that the two orders are not isomorphic anyway.

Comment: Obviously I am not able to solve the problem even though you gave me some hints. However, I give it a try again.I will use that <A,<1> is isomorphic to an ordinal b which is infinite, hence |b|=|b+1|. Let g be the function which is bijection since they are isomorphic, so g: from (A,<1) to (b,<).

Comment: But know we use that there is a bijection between b and S(b)-its successor, which  are not isomorphic, since seg(b+1)={y in A|y<b+1} but this is exactly b, so b is an initial proper segmet of b+1. Hence (b+1,<) is isomorphic to the well-ordered set (A,<2).Now as I had said f(g(x1))>f(g(x2)) if and only if  x2 <2 x1 where f is the bijection and g is the order isomorphism from (A,<1) to (b,<). So we conclude that (A,<1) and (A,<2)  are not isomorphic. Can you look at it now?

Comment: @Tiki: Yes, if you know that $\langle A,\le_1\rangle$ is isomorphic to an ordinal $\beta$, then you can use a bijection $f:\beta\to\beta+1$ to define $\le_2$: $a\le_2b$ if and only if $f(a)\le f(b)$ in the usual order on $\beta+1$. Then $\langle A,\le_2\rangle$ will be isomorphic to $\beta+1$, which is not isomorphic to $\beta$. (This would also be the effect of what I was suggesting; I was avoiding using ordinals, since I wasn’t sure how much you already knew about them.)

Comment: Okay, thank you so much! I was jut unable to make use of the fact that the min element in the first ordered set goes to the last place in A2. How was I supposed to construct the function then? I mean which element in A2 will correspond to the min in A1?

Comment: @Tiki: If you think of $\langle A,\le_1\rangle$ as $\beta$ and $\langle A,\le_2\rangle$ as $\beta+1$, the bijection $f:\beta\to\beta+1$ that I was using in my answer is $f(n)=n-1$ for $1\le n<\omega$, $f(\xi)=\xi$ for $\omega\le\xi<\beta$, and $f(0)=\beta$. You’re welcome!